# Unable to access certain URLs with Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, validation, authentication, url

I am in the process of writing a program whose purpose is centered around generating custom URLs for intelius.com and then extracting data from them with selenium. I have observed interesting behavior that I am unsure how to address.

My program creates URLs after the following pattern: **https://intelius.com/people-search/LASTNAME/CITY-STATE**, but I have found that attempting to access these constructed links consistently leads to a timeout error.

For example, http://intelius.com/people-search/Williams/Brooklyn-NY does not load the expected results page

Digging around in the website's source, I have found what appears to be a link validator script — what exactly that means, I do not know — and am unsure how to proceed.

How exactly would I go about authenticating my queries, without programming selenium to manually input the data into the search textbox and to press the submit button? Is my link-construction approach flawed in some blatantly obvious manner? I am a bit lost and would appreciate some direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is using `http` instead of `https`, and omitting `www` from URL. So this works:

https://www.intelius.com/people-search/Williams/Brooklyn-NY

Comment: Excellent, thank you. It appears the solution was far simpler than I would've expected.

Answer (score -1):

The problem lies in the way the URL being formed. You need to construct and pass the arguments the way the web application understands it. The following works -

https://www.intelius.com/people-search/William-Brooklyn/NY

Comment: no it doesn't: it looks for person called "William Brooklyn" in NY, as opposed to anyone with last name "Williams" in "Brooklyn, NY"